# how to can View information on the second DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I select each row in the grid(gridCustomer) and the second grid(gridOrder) displays object information in my order?

I'll choose the first row of the grid(gridCustomer) but the grid (gridOrder)  will not display anything.

[**Project File**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d24s8dzrxvw2u7r/CoustomersApp4.rar)

[**Video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjXk26VoVrg&feature=youtu.be)

```
    private void gridCustomer_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //var s = gridCustomer.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.gridCustomer.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            var selectedItme = row.Cells["Id"].Value;
            var objOrder = orderBusiness.OrderFindById(Convert.ToInt32(selectedItme));

            gridOrder.DataSource = objOrder;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void gridCustomer_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.gridCustomer.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            var selectedItme = row.Cells["Id"].Value;
            var objOrder = orderBusiness.OrderFindById(Convert.ToInt32(selectedItme));

            /* Add This */
            BindingList<Order> bl = new BindingList<Order> { objOrder };                

            gridOrder.DataSource = bl;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain the code that you added? BindingList<Order> bl = new BindingList<Order> { objOrder };

Comment: The Datasource object cannot be a plain old object. It must support databinding. i.e Must implement IBindingList  or IListSource inerfaces. Check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx